# Using sql an alias in case condition

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to use such a method in mysql view:

This is my computed value of dispatched quantity

```
 (IFNULL((select sum(vin.qty_dsptch) 
             from 
            v_t_invoice vin 

                where (tdl.PRDCT_ID=vin.prdct_id) and (tor.ordr_id=vin.ORDR_ID) 
        group by vin.prdct_id),0)) AS `DISPATCHED_QTY`,
```

And want to use DISPATCHED_QTY alias here

(case when
                (((`tdl`.`qty` - `DISPATCHED_QTY`) > ifnull(`tsr`.`QTY_IN_HAND`, 0))
                    or (ifnull(`tsr`.`QTY_IN_HAND`, 0) <= 0))
            then
                'Shortfall'
            when
                (((`tdl`.`qty` - `DISPATCHED_QTY`) <= ifnull(`tsr`.`QTY_IN_HAND`, 0))
                    or (ifnull(`tsr`.`QTY_IN_HAND`, 0) > 0))
            then
                'Surplus'
        end) AS `SHORTFALL_SURPLUS`

but i am getting a error like "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DISPATCHED_QTY' in 'field list'"

Is there any way to use that alias or need to copy paste that whole computation again in the case conditions

Comment: you can't use column alias  in select   or where  clause or  statements  you could use alias  in order by and in the most recente version in group by  ..  anyway you should post all the code  ..not only part

Comment: Is your query something like: `SELECT calculate_sth AS dispatched_qty, CASE WHEN dispatched_qty and operation...... THEN... END) AS shortfall_surplus`? If that's true you have 2 way to work around: 1. nest the first select to make alias become a column (in nested subquery). 2. Do not use alias, just copy paste all your `calculate_sth` in CASE condition instead of dispatched_qty

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I used the second way... just copied the whole computation again in the case conditions
-Thanks